# Why do I keep getting the error idpiframe_initialization_failed with google calendar api?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I keep getting the error: [image: error]

I have tried everything the other posts have done, but I keep getting the same error, It is so annoying!!!

I tried

1. Re-creating api key
2. creating new project
3. Whitelisting my website

my code is:
[image]
[image]
Can someone please help me solve this issue??

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. It is easier for people to help if they can copy/paste your code and replicate your problem.

Comment: I can't, It says there is too much code

Comment: have you whitelisted localhost?

Comment: Yes, I have whitelisted localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This caught me as well. Try disabling your browser cache in Chrome.

[image: Chrome Cache]

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable third party cookies of your browser